# .htaccess, rewrite url with some exceptions

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an url like this:
    `page.com?c=example1&a=example2`
But i would like to have it like this:
    `page.com/example1/example2`

However if the user is `page.com/public/...` don't do anything, because I have directory `public/css/smth.css` and when i'm trying to access it, it changes to something like `page.com?c=public&a=css/smth.css...` which isn't what I want.

How do I do this only for urls that don't start with `public`?

My current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?c=$1&a=$2
```

Comment: what is your current .htaccess file?

Comment: Please edit your question raather than posting as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .htaccess file needs to look something like this:

```
# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Set the general first level rewrites
RewriteRule ^(.+)/((?!public).*)/(.+)/?$ $1.php?c=$2&a=$3 [NC]
```

I have not tested the above, but it should be along the right lines

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```
RewriteRule ^page.com/public/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/$ page.com?c=public&a=$1 
RewriteRule ^page.com/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/$ page.com?c=$1&a=$2
RewriteRule ^page.com/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ page.com?c=$1&a=$2
```

Comment: what about his not page.com/public/ requirement

Comment: Just add  above the rules..RewriteRule ^page.com/public/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/$ page.com?c=public&a=$1

Comment: @bikashshrestha Why do this in 3 lines when you can do it in one!?

Comment: hi bikash, edit your answer with your comment to make it more complete.